# How to call a class function from navigation drawer in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to call a class function on drawer open and drawer close event can any one help me with this as i am new at react native.

```
    const defaultGetStateForAction =Drawer.router.getStateForAction;
    Drawer.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {

if(state && action.type === 'Navigation/OPEN_DRAWER' ) {
  Alert.alert("drawerOpen")
    //here call a class function with true value
}

if(state && action.type === 'Navigation/DRAWER_CLOSED') {
  Alert.alert("drawerClose")
    //here call a class function  with false value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to solve your problem

[image]

Comment: hi @selva in my code utility is dashboard screen...can you tell me how to call the static function isDrawerOpen beacuse its giving me  undefined is not a function.

Comment: first make sure, your dashboard class is exported properly. Then import your dashboard class where you want to call the method and finally call the method using dashboard class name. eg Dashboard.isDrawerOpen(true), here Dashboard is class name and isDrawerOpen is method name. make sure your method is static.

Comment: yes i have imported and exported correctly.....then i got that issue undefined is not a  function. Please can you run this code and check if it works for u.

Comment: is your method static?. If not declare your method with static keyword. cmd + click on your method. if it redirects to your method declaration class then you`ve done right